# Why is the CommandID in PostgreSQL needed

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, mvcc

I am struggling to understand why the CommandId ([documented here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/storage-page-layout.html#STORAGE-TUPLE-LAYOUT)) is necessary in PostgreSQL. The CommandId is sometimes also called `cmin` and `cmax`.

I understand that the Transaction ID (`xmin/xmax`) is necessary. However the `cmin`/`cmax` values are documented to only be relevant for the current transaction.

I have been looking around pretty much everywhere, but even the `.c`/`.h` files in the PostgreSQL code base do not talk about it a lot.

Comment: See `include/access/htup_details.h`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not include a better description of `cmin`/`cmax`. I have read this before, but the only thing that helped me a bit was the reference of `combocid.c`.

Comment: Short version [cmin/cmax](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAKoxK+6Z248ur31PFMv460OagMOaZBVLRkd7k4bDfmXuUdsE4Q@mail.gmail.com).